# How can I set the Unix epoch of a moment js object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a moment.js object whose Unix epoch value I'd like to change.

Normally I'd use `myMoment = moment(someEpoch);`, but because of design constraints I'm having to pass the object by reference, so I must mutate the value rather than replacing it altogether.

What is the neatest and (ideally) most performant way to do this in v2.15+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m` is a moment object, and `t` is the timestamp to set (in ms), probably the easiest way is:

```
m.add(t-m);
```

Or if you prefer to be more verbose:

```
m.add(t - m.valueOf(), 'ms');
```

Note that the default units are milliseconds when not specified and the input is numeric.  If your input timestamp is in whole seconds, you'd have to multiply it by 1000 in either of the above formulas before subtracting the value of `m`.

However, if you're really after the most efficient code in terms of minimizing total operations performed internally, you could modify moment internals directly.  **Doing so is dangerous in that there's no guarantee the internals won't change between versions.**  Only the public API compatibility is guaranteed, following SemVer rules.  So only do this if you are optimizing for perf and are willing to deal with potentially breaking changes in the future:

```
m._d.setTime(t + ((m._offset || 0) * 60000));
```

This is essentially an inversion of moment's [`valueOf`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.15.1/src/lib/moment/to-type.js#L1-L3) function, and is probably what the implementation would look like if it were built in to moment.

Of course, if you are only working with moments in UTC mode, you can just do:

```
m._d.setTime(t);
```

One last thing, with regard to terminology, you can't actually set "the Unix epoch value", because the epoch is a *fixed* value.  In this context, "epoch" means the timestamp that is zero, which is associated with `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.  It cannot be changed.  You are simply using a "Unix Timestamp in milliseconds", or perhaps an "epoch-based timestamp".  But it is a misnomer for your variable to be named `someEpoch`.

Comment: I decided to pursue the first solution. Modifying internals would be quite dangerous - for me particularly, as because my application re-gathers its NPM dependencies on deployment, it could silently pick up a new minor library version that could then cause a runtime exception. I was able to memoize the results of this particular procedure in the end, so the code is no longer a hot path anyway. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Also, be aware that a future version of moment (v3.0.0) will be using [an immutable API](https://maggiepint.com/2016/07/16/immutability-its-happening/).

Answer (score 0):

moment.js has a method to do that:

`moment.unix(Number)`

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

Comment: This will not mutate an existing instance.